# struts 1.0 logic tag choice - if/else logic

Tags: java, jsp, struts

What I have is a dropdown list. When the user selects a certain option, where each option represents a specific String on the Java server side.

Right now, the Java server side able to check which option is selected, and the number to correspond. At the moment, I am able to output the value in Java backend, not on the JSP page.

Is there an if/else tag for Struts 1.0?

I am not sure which logic tag is the best to pass a Java value for frontend processing:

**JSP page**

```
if(value = 666)
   this textbox is readonly
else
  this textbox row is active
```

My research so far:

Looking at `logic:equal`, it seems to pass a value on the JSP page using taglibs like below. This doesn't work for me, because I want to pass the value *FROM* a Java class on the server side.

```
<logic:equal name="name" property="name" value="<%= theNumber %>" >
```

Comment: r u asking jsp tag for the above logic.you can use jstl tag

Comment: no i'm not. but if it solves the problem, i'm open to all kinds of solutions

Comment: I'd suggest looking at logic:equal again; I believe you've misunderstood. That said, I'd use JSTL when functionality overlaps, particularly in an antiquated version of Struts like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  <c:choose>
     <c:when test="${the number}">
         Both are equal.
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
         Both are not equal.
     </c:otherwise>
     </c:choose>
```

this is jstl tag

```
you need to use
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: is `${the number}` jQuery? would you have a javascript version?

Comment: no it is action variable.we are using in struts2 like this.this might work in struts1.0 as well

Comment: @bouncingHippo jQuery?! It's standard JSP EL notation.

Answer (score 0):

The JSTL answer is the best one, however, in my case it was an old Java legacy application without JSTL and I couldn't introduce it.

This was the requirement I had with some legacy Struts 1.3 code.  Set a checkbox to match the value of a form bean's value from a database call, as in "Y", "N", "", or null.

I also had to keep in within struts logic tags and not use JSTL, which was my original preference.  I know that the struts [docs](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html%3acheckbox) 
said the checkbox should equate to a boolean variable in the 
actionForm, but I used a string value, which worked.

From the docs link above:

**NOTE: The underlying property value associated with this field should be of type boolean, and any value you specify should correspond to one of the Strings that indicate a true value ("true", "yes", or "on"). If you wish to utilize a set of related String values, consider using the multibox tag.**
I had thought about converting my string values to booleans in the 
form, but it took the strings this way.

Last of all, I used some javascript to set the checked status.  All of this is verbose and not the best solution, but faced with the requirement, it does work.

Here is the code:

```
<logic:equal name="<%=formName%>" property="formInd" value="Y">
                <html:checkbox name="<%=formName%>" onchange="setDataChanged()" property="formInd"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
                    document.<%=formName%>.formInd.checked = true;
                </script>              
            </logic:equal>
            <logic:equal name="<%=formName%>" property="formInd" value="N">
                <html:checkbox name="<%=formName%>" onchange="setDataChanged()" property="formInd"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
                        document.<%=formName%>.formInd.checked = false;
                </script>              
            </logic:equal>
            <logic:empty name="<%=formName%>" property="formInd" >
                <html:checkbox name="<%=formName%>" onchange="setDataChanged()" property="formInd"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
                        document.<%=formName%>.formInd.checked = false;
                </script>              
            </logic:empty>
```